# How can I find the last element that does not contain specific child elements?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

So I want to find and click the last product that isn't sold on a product page. Im using xPath to click on the product but I am having issues:

1. Selecting, exclusively, an unsold product.
2. Selecting the last unsold product.

This is an example of the code:

```
<li class =“product_container”>
    <a data-testid=“product__item”>
        <div class=“hover overlay”>
            <img>..</img>
        </div>
    </li>
<li class=“product_container”>
    <a data-testid=“product__item”>…</a>
        <div class=“hover overlay”>
            <div data-testid=“product__sold”>Sold</div>
        </div>
    </li>
```

The first list tag is an unsold product and the second list tag is a sold product (A hover overlay stating "sold")

So far I can find the last loaded element that satisfies the `a/[@data-testid="product__item"]` but every attempt I've made to find element that doesn't contain `div/[@data-testid='product__sold']` doesn't work.

I apologise in advance is my writing and terminology is off, this is the first script I've attempted.

Comment: I've managed to identify the sold items using this `//a[@data-testid="product__item"]//child::div[@data-testid="product__sold"]` .

But i wish to select the last element that doesn't have that div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bases on this xml:

```
  <li class="product_container">
    <a data-testid="product__item">...</a>
    <div class="hover overlay">
      <img>..</img>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="product_container">
    <a data-testid="product__item">...</a>
    <div class="hover overlay">
      <div data-testid="product__sold">Sold</div>
    </div>
  </li>
```

You need:

```
//li[not(descendant::div[@data-testid='product__sold'])][position()=last()]/a
```

The result is:

```
<a data-testid="product__item">...</a>
```

Comment: this was a small typo, but your answer doesnt answer my q

Comment: Sorry, now my answer was full of typo's

Answer (score 0):

You can search for an element that doesn't have sibling with `data-testid="product__sold"`

```
(//a[last()][@data-testid="product__item"][not(following-sibling::div/div[@data-testid="product__sold"])])[last()]
```

Comment: This selects the last loaded product regardless of whether or not it's been sold.

Comment: @SebastianChu This xpath is based on the html snippets you posted.

Comment: the 'not' doesn't seem to be effective. it still just finds the last element that [@data-testid="product__item"] but has a following sibling that is sold.

Comment: This worked in identifying the first 'sold' product but I am unsure as to where to put the 'not' function

`//a[last()][@data-testid="product__item"]//child::div[@data-testid="product__sold"]`